# javascript naming a function in an object

Tags: javascript

Which one should I use between these two, is there one that has an advantage over the other?

```
// 1st
{ ["test"]() { return 1; } }

// 2nd
{ "test": function () { return 1; } }
```

Comment: Or `{ "test"(){ return 1; } }`. It’s not exactly the same as `{ "test": function () { return 1; } }`, as the short-hand syntax creates non-constructible methods, rather than constructible functions.

Comment: It's an ES6 new feature. See comparison [here](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) and [here](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"test": function () { return 1; }` is the old way and `"test"() { return 1; }` the new way with the `function` keyword being ommited.

Also note the `[]` here allow you to use a variable as identifier

```js
let name = "test1"
let a = {
  "test2": function () { return "you called test2" },
  "test3"() { return "you called test3" },
  
  
  [name]() { return "you called test1" },
  [name + "1"]() { return "you called " + name + "1" }
}

// written differently works the same
console.log( a.test2() ) // "you called test2" <-- the old way declared one
console.log( a.test3() ) // "you called test3" <-- new way declared one

// same call
console.log( a[name]() ) // "you called test1" <-- declared using
console.log( a.test1() ) // "you called test1" <-- [name]() {...}

// the [...] notation allow the build of identifier freely 
console.log( a.test11() ) // "you called test11"      <-- declared using
console.log( a[name + "1"]() ) // "you called test11" <-- [name + "1"]() {...}
```

since Javascript like many other language tend to avoid deprecation for old program to continue working, you get to a point where one thing can be done many way

Comment: Wow... Old vs new way is great.

Answer (score 1):

It allows to use variable property names:

```js
let propName = "test"
console.log({ [propName]() { return 1 } }.test());
```

Answer (score 1):

Advantages:

- Functions are declared normally and therefore have names. (Whereas
  with the `{name: function() { ... }}` format, all of your functions
  are anonymous, even though the properties referencing them have
  names.) Names help tools help you, from showing call stacks in a
  debugger, to telling you what function threw an exception. (2015
  Update: The latest JavaScript specification, ECMAScript 6th edition,
  defines a large number of ways the JavaScript engine must infer a
  function's name. One of those is when the function is assigned to a
  property as in our `{name: function() { ... }}` example. So as
  engines implement ES6, this reason will go away.)
- Gives you the freedom of having private functions only used by your
  module (such as my `internalSomething` above). No other code on the
  page can call those functions; they're truly private. Only the ones you export at the end, in the return statement, are visible
  outside the scoping function.
- Makes it easy to return different functions depending on environment,
  if the implementation just changes completely (such as      IE-vs-W3C
  stuff, or SVG vs. Canvas, etc.).